# PHP mysql order by if this == this, then order by this, else order by this?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a server list, and first of all I want to order the servers by the most online users,

but in case that there is a server that is currently in progress + has the most players online at the moment, I want to ignore it.

Basically order by PLAYERS COUNT + status = available, but it doesn't work?

```
$query = $this->controller->db->fetch("argonite_servers", null, null, "server_status = 'Available', server_players");
```

And this is my method:

```
    public function fetch($table, array $criteria = null, $limit = null, $order = null)
    {
        // The query base
        $query = "SELECT * FROM $table";
        
        // Start checking
        if ($criteria) {
            $query .= ' WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', array_map(function($column) {
                return "$column = ?";
            }, array_keys($criteria)));
        }
        
        // limit
        if ($limit) 
        {
            $query .= " LIMIT ". $limit;
        }
        
        //order
        if ($order)
        {       
            $query .= " ORDER BY ".$order." DESC";
        }
        
        $check = $this->pdo->prepare($query) or die('An error has occurred with the following message:' . $query);
        if ($criteria)
            $check->execute(array_values($criteria));
        else
            $check->execute();
        return $check;
    }
```

Why won't it display all servers whom are available + has the most players at the top?

Right now, my table shows this:

[image: img]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/e30bd07841cdec90e6854c55baddaf9e.png))</sub>
;

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Show the query, not the code.

Comment: The query is "SELECT * FROM argonite_servers ORDER BY server_players, server_status = 'Available' DESC"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're where clause is probably `select * from argonite_servers where server_status = 'Available' order by server_players desc;`  It looks like you've merged your `order` and `criteria` clauses in your method call instead of keeping them separate.

So instead of

```
$query = $this->controller->db->fetch("argonite_servers", null, null, "server_status = 'Available', server_players");
```

You might want:

```
$query = $this->controller->db->fetch("argonite_servers", "server_status ='Available'", null, "server_players");
```

EDIT:

To keep the 'available' status showing you are lucky that 'Available' is alphabetically sorted ahead of so do this:

```
$query = $this->controller->db->fetch("argonite_servers", null, null, "server_status ASC, server_players");
```

Comment: But that way it will only fetch available servers, I want still to show them up, but just not at the top of the table (if there are ones that are available).

Comment: Basically what I need is, ORDER BY (if there is available servers, order all available servers by player count) else, order all servers by player count. Someone told me I can use MYSQL cases, but I am not to sure how.

Comment: The edit work? In essence, since "Available" comes before "Full" you are ordering by the first column alphabetically ascending and then ordering the number of players descending.  This is kind of just lucky that the ordering works out... if you had a third status like "Accessable" (Ac < Av < Fu) then you'd need to provide a different order clause.